# Low Redis Hit Rate? (20%)

Tags: magento2, cache, full-page-cache, redis

I just checked hit rate of Redis via (https://gist.github.com/kabel/10023961).

The hit rate is around %20.x - is this normal?

[image]

The machine has a ton of RAM and CPU available. Redis is locally installed. Redis is serving sessions and the Full-Page Cache.

Config:

```
'session' => [
    'save' => 'redis',
    'redis' => [
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => '6379',
        'password' => '',
        'timeout' => '2.5',
        'persistent_identifier' => '',
        'database' => '2',
        'compression_threshold' => '2048',
        'compression_library' => 'gzip',
        'log_level' => '3',
        'max_concurrency' => '10',
        'break_after_frontend' => '5',
        'break_after_adminhtml' => '30',
        'first_lifetime' => '600',
        'bot_first_lifetime' => '60',
        'bot_lifetime' => '7200',
        'disable_locking' => '1',
        'min_lifetime' => '60',
        'max_lifetime' => '2592000'
    ]
],
'cache' => [
    'frontend' => [
        'default' => [
            'backend' => '\\Magento\\Framework\\Cache\\Backend\\Redis',
            'backend_options' => [
                'server' => 'localhost',
                'database' => '0',
                'port' => '6379',
                'compress_data' => '1',
                'compression_lib' => 'gzip',
                'preload_keys' => [
                    't8a_EAV_ENTITY_TYPES:hash',
                    't8a_GLOBAL_PLUGIN_LIST:hash',
                    't8a_DB_IS_UP_TO_DATE:hash',
                    't8a_SYSTEM_DEFAULT:hash'
                ]
            ],
            'id_prefix' => '16a_'
        ],
        'page_cache' => [
            'backend' => '\\Magento\\Framework\\Cache\\Backend\\Redis',
            'backend_options' => [
                'server' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => '6379',
                'database' => '1',
                'compress_data' => '1',
                'compression_lib' => 'gzip'
            ],
            'id_prefix' => '16a_'
        ]
    ]
],
```

What gives why would hit rate be so low? Is this normal for Magento 2?

UPDATE:

I think I know why the miss rate is so high. The sessions are being saved for too long ('max_lifetime' => '2592000' - had to set this because of Magento 2.4.3 bug) and it causes misses because the user doesn't revisit.

Comment: preload_keys' => [
                    't8a_EAV_ENTITY_TYPES:hash',
                    't8a_GLOBAL_PLUGIN_LIST:hash',
                    't8a_DB_IS_UP_TO_DATE:hash',
                    't8a_SYSTEM_DEFAULT:hash'
                ]


also, are you sure you have keys like this? probably ':hash' is wrong

Comment: Thanks I'll check

Comment: You should definitely separate cache and sessions to different servers. Then you can set proper limits and policies for each and see stats that are meaningful. The number of keys hit only once is not relevant to hit rate, the misses are just when a key requested did not exist at the time it was requested.

Comment: The issue was in the Magento bug. They fixed it in the next version that was released. The hit rate after new version jumped up to 80%.